# How to make google earth iframe shim semi-transparent

Tags: javascript, transparent, google-earth

I am attempting to implement a iframe shim to render custom html content on top of the google earth plugin.  I am successful in rendering the overlay, however I would also like to make both the iframe and custom html semi-transparent.  The custom html content does not render when setting "allowTransparency" to true and lowering the opacity of the iframe.

Below is sample code

```
<body>

   <div id="earth"></div>

   <iframe allowTransparency="true" style="position:absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:200px; height:500px; background:#222; opacity:0.5; border:none; z-index:100;"></iframe>

   <div id="shimdiv" style="position:absolute; top:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:200px; height:500px; background:#222; opacity:0.5; border:none; z-index:100;"></div>

</body>
```

All the examples I have found render full opacity html content.  Does anyone know of a work around to allow for transparency?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excuse me, was You successful in overlaying semi-transparent iframe over the google earth plugin?

Comment: It is possible in some OS/browser combinations but not all.

Comment: @lifeIsGood Do you know why it only works on some OS/browser combinations? I only got it to work on Mac with both safari and Firefox. 
Is there any browser where this works on Windows?